# Resuming activity

Tags: discussion

It's really hard to do the right thing, especially when "the right thing" isn't even known. When I announced my leave of absence along with over 30 other moderators, I hoped that SE would to recognize that, IMHO, they were really screwing things up.

From the looks of it, SE has started paying attention. They've made some positive steps, such as setting up new communication channels, setting up committees to engage the community ([blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/?cb=1)), and—for us moderators—talking to us a bit more before making community-wide changes and even making changes based on our feedback. They've also screwed some new stuff up, most recently with the inclusion of irrelevant but mandatory demographic questions on the [feedback survey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/Z2YDMRD). Importantly (to me, at least), they've released their "fix things" strategy along with a timeline to the entire community ([blog post again](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/?cb=1)). That's not just a commitment to their users, that's something investors can now expect and demand of leadership.

Will they do any of the positive things they said they'll do? Most likely. Will they screw up even more stuff in the future? Almost certainly. However, are they *trying?* Yes.

Culture shifts are difficult. Publicly announced culture shifts are *really* difficult. I really appreciate SE's acknowledgement and public commitment to fixing an unhealthy culture. To that extent, I happily resume my duties as moderator.

Comment: Welcome back! I'm glad you sorted out the conflict with S.Exchange.

Comment: This sounds promising. However, as a run-of-the-mill user who *very infrequently* looks into Meta.SE, your post is the first I heard of this. Naively, I would have expected a blog post or a featured Meta.SE thread. Is there anywhere for us run-of-the-mill users to learn about how SE plan on moving forward?

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica [The “loop” has arrived. What does the community think about it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339050/476162).  As you know, this is still going on:  [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/476162).

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica - Sorry, didn't take the time to add links earlier. Note that this is on the sidebar... it's featured more heavily on stackoverflow, less on the other topical sites. Add that to the list of things they're still screwing up :(

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I have read that blog post. Honestly, if that is all we will get, it just adds insult to injury. ("One theme we examine is what you find most frustrating about using Stack Overflow" - with precisely *nothing* about what has a large proportion of serious users up in arms.) I was hoping for something I hadn't seen and been insulted by yet. Again, thank you.

Comment: Welcome back! I appreciate the nuanced take on the situation.

Comment: So you're dumping on Monica, and the principle regarding her reinstatement  here then? (I am not a fan of Monica's take on grammar and some other things, but that's irrelevant). No, you don't have my support. It's not ok. What indication is there that you will not be bought off each time SE does everything they want to do when it's wildly wrong? Be a member, not a  member.

Comment: @Araucaria - I don't understand most of your comment. That said, regarding support, I'm not looking for support, I'm simply explaining my own actions. I have little to say regarding Monica beyond what I [said earlier](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4588/leave-of-absence#comment13933_4605). If you wish to discuss further please feel free to [reach out in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/23009/eykanal).